# We've all met up vs. We all have met up

Tags: word-choice, word-order

Which word order should I use in an informal letter?

> It’s been a while since **we all have** met up

or

> It's been a while since **we've all** met up

Comment: It really doesn't matter. The second is _more_ informal.

Comment: Another interesting question that could be framed is this: What's the difference between _It's been a while since we all met up_. AND _It's been a while since we all have met up_?